# Delete All Text After Bookmark

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am running a script on a word doc that generates a bunch of text. I have a button that I would like to be able to use to clear all of the text. How can I delete all text after a bookmark?

Answer (score 1):

That's as simple as:

```
With ActiveDocument
  .Range(.Bookmarks("MyBookmark").Range.End, .Range.End).Delete
End With
```